# Chef : how to give access of a vault for multiple servers

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-vault

I use below command for creating a new chef vault-
knife vault create   -A  -M client -S 'name:' -J

My question is how can I give access of this chef vault to multiple nodes?

Also, what are the different ways, this access can be granted ? (can be via node names, role names etc).
I need to know the commands for the search query

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `-S` is a Chef search query, which is normally used to select which nodes should be given access. `name:` is not a valid query, but it's hard to tell if you meant that literally. You can also use the `-A` flag (which, again, is used incorrectly above) to add individual users or clients by name (I know it says `--admins` but it works with node names too).

As an infosec practitioner I am also obligated to warn you that use of the `-S` search query option can be unsafe under certain attack models. Specifically a compromised node can change its own attributes such that the next time someone runs a vault refresh, the node is incorrectly given access. This isn't the worst of all possible security holes but just be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Giving access to a vault-item to multiple nodes/clients can be achieved using `-C, --clients CLIENTS` option, where `CLIENTS` is the comma-separated list of the clients.

e.g.:

```
knife vault create <vault> <item> -C "client1,client2,client3,... ,clientN" -J <json_file_for_item>
```

As per the [CHEF-vault reference](https://docs.chef.io/chef_vault.html).